# Append text to a span targeted by the content of sibling span

Tags: jquery

I have this structure:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <span class="text-primary">Built-up</span>:
  <span class="text-muted">3000</span>
</li>
```

Using jQuery, I need to **append the unit (m²)** to the **3000** so that it looks like this **3000m²** .

I can't do this with CSS because I cannot modify the html and the list order changes so I need to target the text.

Here's my code:

```js
$("span:contains('Built-up'~.text-muted)").append("<p>m²</p>");
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="list-group-item">
  <span class="text-primary">Built-up</span>:
  <span class="text-muted">3000</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, move `~.text-muted` out of `:contains()` like below

```
$("span:contains('Built-up')~.text-muted")
```

**Demo**

```js
$("span:contains('Built-up')~.text-muted").append("<p>m²</p>");
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block
}

li.list-group-item p{
 display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="list-group-item">
  <span class="text-primary">Built-up</span>:
  <span class="text-muted">3000</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works, thank you! I will chose this as the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span:contains('Built-up')~.text-muted").append("m<sup>2</sup>"); 
})
```